# Flask-SQLAlchemy Grid.js Slow Query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is a query that is taking some time using Flask-SQLAlchemy, the raw query when ran in SQL Server is actually quite fast.

```
search = request.args.get('search')
    # sort = request.args.get('sort')
    start = request.args.get('start', type=int, default=-1)
    length = request.args.get('length', type=int, default=-1)

    base_query = db.session.query(
            Experience.uID, 
            Person.ID, 
            Person.fullName, 
            Experience.companyID, 
            Experience.jobTitle, 
            Company.companyName,
            Experience.role,
            ).join(Person).join(Company)

    # if start != -1 and length != -1:
    #     base_query = base_query.order_by(Experience.uID).offset(start).limit(length)

    if search:
        base_query = base_query.filter(
                db.or_(
                Experience.companyID.like(f'%{search}%'),
                Experience.jobTitle.like(f'%{search}%'),
                Experience.role.like(f'%{search}%'),
                Person.fullName.like(f'%{search}%'),
                Company.companyName.like(f'%{search}%'),
                ))

        total_records = base_query.count()

        base_query = base_query.order_by(Experience.uID).offset(start).limit(length).all()

    else:
        total_records = base_query.count()
        base_query = base_query.order_by(Experience.uID).offset(start).limit(length).all()
```

And to send the dict to Grid.js on the Flask template

```
query_data = []

    for i in base_query:
        query_data.append({
            'uniqueID': i[0],
            'personID': i[1],
            'fullName': i[2],
            'companyID': i[3],
            'jobTitle': i[4],
            'companyName': i[5],
            'role': i[6],
        }) 

    return {
            'data': query_data, 
            'total': total_records,
        }
```

When only using one of the filters the query is much quicker, however I would like to keep all the filters.

When using a query with only one table and multiple filters on that table it is responsive as it should be. With a joined table and multiple filters it slows down dramatically.

EDIT:

Below is the output from Flask-SQLAlchemy. This query runs with ease in SQL Management Studio in less than a second. The bottleneck seems to be occurring within python.

```
SELECT [xPDL_Experience].[UniqueID] AS [xPDL_Experience_UniqueID], [xPDL_Person].[PersonID] AS [xPDL_Person_PersonID], [xPDL_Person].[FullName] AS [xPDL_Person_FullName], [xPDL_Experience].[CompanyID] AS [xPDL_Experience_CompanyID], [xPDL_Experience].[JobTitle] AS [xPDL_Experience_JobTitle], [xPDL_Company].[Name] AS [xPDL_Company_Name], [xPDL_Experience].[BoardPosition] AS [xPDL_Experience_BoardPosition]
FROM [xPDL_Experience] JOIN [xPDL_Person] ON [xPDL_Person].[PersonID] = [xPDL_Experience].[PersonID] JOIN [xPDL_Company] ON [xPDL_Company].[CompanyID] = [xPDL_Experience].[CompanyID]
WHERE [xPDL_Experience].[JobTitle] LIKE ? OR [xPDL_Experience].[BoardPosition] LIKE ? OR [xPDL_Person].[FullName] LIKE ? OR [xPDL_Company].[Name] LIKE ? ORDER BY [xPDL_Experience].[UniqueID], [xPDL_Person].[FullName], [xPDL_Person].[PersonID], [xPDL_Company].[Name]
 OFFSET ? ROWS
 FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Use e.g. `print(base_query)` to obtain the generated SQL SELECT, and then show us the EXPLAIN SELECT ... query plan output. We're trying to identify how the python query is different, and what is "bad" about the query, e.g. perhaps it prevents us from using our favorite index.

Comment: @spt97 Also maybe double check that other queries are not being executed for some reason by setting `echo = True` on the engine.

Comment: @IanWilson No other queries are being executed. I have edited the main post with the base query.

Comment: Seems like you should be joining from person to company, instead of from experience to company.  Are you copying and pasting the query from SQL alchemy into  studio?